# What are the operational times for public transport in Marrakech, and where can I find a schedule?

Tags: public-transport, morocco, marrakech

Marrakech has a public bus transport system, but what are its operating times? I ask because [Wikitravel states for the single bus route that operates between the city and its airport to be](http://wikitravel.org/en/Marrakech#Get_around) "6.15am to 9.15pm". Is this true for other bus routes too - in case I need to plan my travel around the city accordingly?

As a broader question, do public buses in Marrakech run according to any kind of schedule that I can refer to, perhaps online or in printed form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good luck if you want to take a bus in Marrakech ...

According to the Moroccan Airports Authority there is [a shuttle between the airport and the city center](http://www.onda.ma/ONDA/An/Espaces/EspacePassagers/LeReseauAeroportuaireONDA/Lesaeroports/Fiches+d%E2%80%99identit%C3%A9+par+a%C3%A9roport/MARRAKECH/Acc%C3%A8s.htm). This shuttle is running at an hourly frequency, between 6.25 am and 12.25 am on the following route:

Departure Airport - Hivernage - Jemaa El Fna - Bab Doukkala- Gueliz - ONCF Station - Arrival Airport

The one-way ticket costs 30 MAD and the round trip 50 MAD.

There is a place not far from the Jemaa El Fna square where you can catch the main city buses.

On the other hand, note that the main sights can and must be visited on foot. For instance, there is no bus crossing the Medina. If you want to go to a place a bit outside, such as the Majorelle Gardens, you can take a so-called small taxi. These taxis have meters, and the drivers are supposed to use them (you have to insist). Note that 25 MAD will take you rather far already.

Comment: You were right, I ultimately didn't need to use any public transport. Not even taxis even, as I found the train station / Gueliz / New City area within comfortable walking distance for me. I updated the answer though with updated prices for bus tickets, the official site gives outdated figures.

Comment: Taxi to the airport costs 80 MAD.